# I'm looking for a Frappe Gantt equivalent to apply in my Django project

Tags: django, frappe

I'm sorry in advance if I could not phrase my issue right, I'm currently new to Django and developing a project. I was looking for an interactive drag and drop Gantt chart solution for my project. I stumbled on Frappe Gantt chart and found it perfect for my requirements. However, I understand that I can't really apply it in Django. Is there a way to apply? an alternative?

I have looked around and found some solutions, but none of them were compatible as frappe. Moreover, there's not much around that are open source with appropriate license. I thought about creating the chart from scratch, but I'm not sure where to start.